# No module named Matplotlib at VScode

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Even though I installed matplotlib by pip in Vscode, it still says there is no module named "matplotlib". When I use Jupyter notebook instead it works. How can I use Matplotlib in Vscode?

Comment: it may be you are using different python installation / virtualenv / ... Check for `import sys; sys.path()`

Comment: Did you install it globally or in a venv? If in a venv did you source  / activate it? Do you have single python in your system or python 2.x and 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First check the version of python you are using in your Jupyter Notebook.
2. Make sure you are using the same version of python in vscode:

Click `{}python` in the right bottom.

[image]

Then select the correct python version in the top middle.

[image]